# Counting in facet results

Tags: solr, lucene, facet, solandra

By counting in facet results I mean resolve the problem:

I have 7 documents:

```
A1   B1   C1
A2   B1   C1
A3   B2   C1
A4   B2   C2
A5   B3   C2
A6   B3   C2
A7   B3   C2
```

If I make the facet query by field B, get the result: B1=2, B2=2, B3=3.

```
A1   B1   C1
A2   B1   C1     2 - facing by B
--------------====
A3   B2   C1
A4   B2   C2     2 - facing by B
--------------====
A5   B3   C2
A6   B3   C2
A7   B3   C2     3 - facing by B
--------------====
```

I want to get additional information, something like count in results, by field C. So, how can I query to get a result similar to the following:

```
A1   B1   C1
A2   B1   C1     2, 1 - facing by B, count C in facet results
--------------=======
A3   B2   C1
A4   B2   C2     2, 2 - facing by B, count C in facet results
--------------=======
A5   B3   C2
A6   B3   C2
A7   B3   C2     2, 1 - facing by B, count C in facet results
--------------=======
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [Facet Pivots](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-792)
This will help you get the results and counts of hierarchies.

This is available in Solr 4.0 trunk build. So you may need to apply the patch.

References -
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting

Comment: I use Solandra that integrates Solr 3.4 with Cassandra. So, is there any way to solve this problem with Solr 3.4?

Comment: Thanks I have calculated some aggregation data to get appropriate result.
Thanks for your advice